Sort Seaborn Histogram by Count in a Binary Variable
I am working with pandas and seaborn to generate a fairly large barplot. The x axis consists of multiple identifying numbers, while the y axis displays counts. I am trying to order the x axis and sort the barplot in descending order based on counts of a binary variable (which is shown with seaborn barplot'shue feature.)
Currently, I have tried to pass a sorted dataframe into the by parameter of barplot, as such:
count= df['binary_variable'].value_counts()
df['count'] = df['binary_variable'].map(count)
df.sort_values(by = 'count', ascending = False, inplace = True)

sns.barplot(data = df, x = 'ID', hue = 'binary_variable')

However, this seems to have no effect on the barplot. After inspecting the sorted dataframe using .head(), it appears the sorting mechanism works. However, it does not affect the barplot.
I have also tried to change the x axis into type str with df['unique_id'] = df['unique_id'].astype(str), which seemed to work in the case of a question posed here: Seaborn catplot Sort by Count column
However, this method does not work in this case.
Here is some dummy data that may help with this case:
ID | binary_variable
1          1
1          1
1          0
2          1
2          0
3          1
4          1
4          1
4          1
4          1

In this dummy case, I would want the bar with ID 4 to be leftmost as it has the highest count of 1 in the binary_variable column.

Side note: this sounds like a bar chart, not a histogram.

I believe you are correct - I do now have a new error: Horizontal orientation requires numeric x variable. Changing my x axis variable to an integer did not fix this.

Your code looks very weird.  You seem to be counting a "binary variable" independent of the "unique id".  How should that influence the order of the "unique id"s?  Can you please add some dummy test data (in text or code form)? Also, for a histogram with discrete x-values, you need discrete=True.

Would df = pd.DataFrame({'binary_variable': [True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False], 'unique_id': [2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2]}) be a good test case?  Can you add an image of the plot you get with your test case and an explanation how you want it to be different?

Yes, that test case appears to be useful. I have also edited the original question for more context.

You want the order to be on the unique_id, counting where binary variable is 1?

Yes, that is desired. Thanks for the clarification.

From the comments, I understand you want to have a plot with counts of a "unique id" and a "binary variable", ordered by the count of the "unique id" where "binary variable" equals 1.
Seaborn's histplot and countplot don't have an order= parameter. But sns.barplot does.
The code below has some comments trying to clarify the steps.
df.loc[df['binary_variable'] == 1, ['unique_id', 'binary_variable']] makes a subset with 'binary_variable' == 1 and selects the 'unique_id' and 'binary_variable' (in that order). On this selection, the values are counted. .reset_index() converts the index of the count dataframe back to regular columns.
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some dummy test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'binary_variable': np.random.randint(0,2,200),
                   'unique_id': np.random.randint(1,6,200) })

# count where binary_variable == 1, and sort by count
count1 = df.loc[df['binary_variable'] == 1, ['unique_id', 'binary_variable']].value_counts(sort=True, ascending=False).reset_index()
# count where binary_variable == 0
count0 = df.loc[df['binary_variable'] == 0, ['unique_id', 'binary_variable']].value_counts().reset_index()
# concatenate both count dataframes
both_counts = pd.concat([count1, count0], ignore_index=True)

# create a barplot of the counts, the order is taken from count1
# the hue order is changed to have the 1's first
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.barplot(data=both_counts, x='unique_id', order=count1['unique_id'],  y='count',
            hue='binary_variable', hue_order=[1, 0], palette='summer')
sns.despine()


